# Getting Error 0040 when deploying an app with EF&MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am deploying an application that uses Entity Framework with MySQL. I've got this error when I access the page. In my developer machine the system works perfectly, but in the server that I deploy the solution is not working.

```
The scheme specified is not valid.
error 0040: The bool type is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only 
PrimitiveType can be used without qualification.
error 0040: Type usmallint is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only 
PrimitiveType can be used without qualification.
```

Comment: Error 0040 is not a MySQL error - its an error in the ADO.NET stack (which it would have been useful to mention that you use "Entity Framework" is not a very descriptive term). I'm guessing that you try to use some primitive types which are not acceptable by MySQL and are defined by an external resource that you do not have on the server. If you can provide a few more details, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I think that is a problem with the version of the PROVIDER for ADO.NET to MySQL that It's necessary to work with the Entity Framework. In my developer machine, It's work, but in the remote server It's not work. I think that in the remote server host they not have the most recente version of the provider http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html